# Fastest way of checking if two lists have at least 2 common items in Python?

Tags: python

```
 a={}

 t= list(map(int,input().split()))
 n=t[0]
 k=t[1]

 for i in range(n):
    a.update({i:[]})

 ids=[] 

 for i in range(n):
     k=input().split()
     ids.append(set(k[1:]))


 def ifrel(i, j):
    if i==j:
      return False
    return len(ids[i] & ids[j]) >= 2

 for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
       if ifrel(i,j):
          a[i].append(j)
 stack=[]
 res=[]
 def iterdfs(g,s):
     stack.append(s)
     while stack!=[]:
       k=stack.pop()
       if k not in res:
          res.append(k)
       for i in g[k]:
          if i not in res: 
         stack.append(i)
     return res

  print(len(iterdfs(a,0)))
```

Here is the Final Solution Using Set, but still I am getting TLE!

ids[] is a list containing lists eg: ids= [ ['1','2','3']] . Will using Dictionary improve the speed?

I had some troubel with editing as it is my first question in Stack Overflow.

The Problem I am trying to solve is:
https://www.codechef.com/IOIPRAC/problems/INOI1302/

Comment: Can you paste the formatted code please?

Comment: Also, what relevance does the code have? Does it almost work? Do you get an error? And have you debugged it?

Comment: Before it was edited it said something about how it works correctly, but it's too slow

Comment: They wanted a faster way of checking if two lists share two or more items

Comment: The code is working but I need to perform this operation for multiple lists. I need a faster way of doing it.

Comment: Excuse me, what is TLE?

Comment: @VPfB TLE: Time Limit Exceeded. It means my code is slower than what they are expecting.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Thank you, today I learned a new TLA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the *fastest* solution, it's not going to be concise. Here's an attempt that is worst case O(A + B), but will exit as soon as two matches are found and is best case Ω(B), where B is the shorter of the two lists.

```
def check_common_items(A, B, n=2):

    # set B to be the shorter list, len is O(1)
    if len(B) < len(A):
        A, B = B, A

    B_set = set(B) # O(len(B))

    count = 0
    for a in A: # worst case O(len(A))
        if a in B_set: # O(1)
            count += 1
            if count == n:
                return True
    return False
```

However, most implementations that use sets will be asymptotically efficient. For example, the following function probably isn't too much slower.

```
def check_common_items(A, B, n=2):
    return len(set(A) & set(B)) >= n
```

Comment: Still getting TLE!

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Then some other part of your algorithm is probably inefficient

Answer (score 2):

Use a set.

```
In [1]: lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [2]: lst2 = [3, 4, 5, 6]
In [3]: set(lst1).intersection(set(lst2))
Out[3]: {3, 4}
In [4]: len(set(lst1).intersection(set(lst2)))
Out[4]: 2
```

Comment: By the way, your list approach says 2 for `sum([4,1,0].count(x) > 0 for x in [1,1,3])`

Comment: Ah. I didn't think of that. I'll remove that.

Comment: `sum([4,1,0].count(x) > 0 for x in set([1,1,3]))` would work. It had to change that in my answer too

Comment: Yea, I considered that. But I wanted a list only approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(list1,list2):
   if len([elem for elem in set(list1) if elem in list2])>=2:return True
   return False
```

Use this function. It makes a list of the common items and checks the length of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to come up with a more efficient algorithm, rather than checking against the entirety of both lists, you can terminate once you've identified two duplicates:

```
a = ['some', 'list']
b = ['some', 'other', 'list']
duplicate_count = 0
my_bool = False
for item in a:
    if item in b:
        duplicate_count += 1
    if duplicate_count >= 2:
        my_bool = True
        break
```

The algorithm is still O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case, but it has the possibility of terminating early